# Is activity same as Java Class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have just started learning android and am not able to understand what an activity is. My question is, is creating an activity same as creating a new class? A class is just referred as an activity in android.
Also can't a UI screen have multiple java classes or one UI page will have only one java class?

Comment: There are lots of links on stackoverflow explaining what an activity is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180180/android-can-somebody-please-explain-what-is-activity-context-intent-in-android

Comment: One screen can have multiple classes attached... They're called fragments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View)

We can say Activity is a Java class that the user can interact with.